# Semigroup, unique decomposition

Tags: logic, semigroups

Exercise 2 on p. 7 of *Notes on Logic* by Roger Lyndon asks the reader to prove for the semigroup $E$ the following theorem:

$ef=gh$ implies either $e=gk$ and $h=kf$ for some $k$ or else $g=ek$ and $f=kh$ for some $k$.

I understand that because of the unique decomposition of a string and associativity it's possible, but cannot express in math symbols properly.

My approach

$ef=gh=z_1\dots z_n$ where $z_1,\dots z_n$- primes.

$gh=(z_1\dots z_k)(z_{k+1}\dots z_n)$

$ef=(z_1\dots z_k\dots z_l)(z_{l+1}\dots z_n)$

$ef=(z_1\dots z_k)(z_{k+1}\dots z_l)(z_{l+1}\dots z_n)=g(kf)=gh$

Comment: How is the reader of your question supposed to know what the semigroup $E$ is?

Comment: @AlexKruckman it's from a book about logic, grammar, language. So it should be about the semigroup of sentences from some $L$anguage.

Comment: My point is that you should edit your question to include a precise definition of $E$ (and also a precise reference to the source of the question, if it comes from a textbook).

Comment: @AlexKruckman the problem from Notes on Logic by Lyndon, ex. 2, p. 15. I just copied & pasted. I don't know which semigroup the author is talking about. I suspect that that theorem doesn't hold for any semigroups. If you know how to prove it for any semigroup, please share, because I cannot prove it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to read more carefully, then. The semigroup $E$ is defined on the previous page, and the theorem does indeed hold for this semigroup. (By the way, the exercise is on p. 7, not p. 15, and the definition of $E$ is on p. 6. It may be p. 15 of some electronic copy you have, but proper references give the page numbers as listed in the book.)

Comment: @oowwee If its a free monoid then thats a very important condition. This is not true for arbitrary semigroup

Answer (score 1):

The semigroup $E$ is defined to be the set of all "expressions" from a set of symbols $S$, where an expression is a string of the form $s_1\dots s_n$ with $n\geq 0$ and each $s_i\in S$. The semigroup operation is concatenation.

Suppose $e,f,g,h\in E$ with $ef = gh$. Your approach is correct: write $ef = gh$ as $s_1\dots s_n$. Then there is some $\ell,m\leq n$ such that $e = s_1\dots s_\ell$, $f = s_{\ell+1}\dots s_n$, $g = s_1\dots s_m$, and $h = s_{m+1}\dots s_n$.

*Case 1:* $\ell\leq m$. Then letting $k = s_{\ell+1}\dots s_m$, we have $g = (s_1\dots s_\ell)(s_{\ell+1}\dots s_m) = ek$ and $f = (s_{\ell+1}\dots s_m)(s_{m+1}\dots s_n) = kh$.

*Case 2:* $m<\ell$. Then letting $k = s_{m+1}\dots s_\ell$, we have $e = (s_1\dots s_m)(s_{m+1}\dots s_\ell) = gk$ and $h = (s_{m+1}\dots s_\ell)(s_{\ell+1}\dots s_n) = kf$.

Comment: This semigroup is called the free monoid with generators $S$

Comment: @Jakobian Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that in my answer - but proving this is actually the next exercise in Lyndon's book!